# Why am I getting captcha more than once per session?

Tags: bug, captcha

That's a bit meta, a bit stackoverflow question - what's the point of asking a CAPTCHA challenge to a user that's already replied the CAPTCHA question properly?

I've been giving several short answers on SO and I got the time limit throttle. I kept pressing "submit" because I didn't know whether the three minutes had already passed or not and pretty often I would get challenged by the CAPTCHA.

Even after replying to it correctly, I got another CAPTCHA question next time I rushed the "submit" button. Why is it made this way?

Comment: Because you're a bot. A clever one, I have to admit, but a bot nonetheless.

Comment: Haha! (sorry, had to). I actually wonder if I'd pass the Turing test right now. I'm pretty sleepy.

Comment: I think this is somewhat by design, if you perform enough actions you might get more than one CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 2):

A once-per-session verification would mean that a human could easily solve the captcha once and then have a valid session for the bot to run in. For that reason one cannot be 100 % certain that you to are a human so you get the capctha again if you show too much of a bot-like behavior.